# How do I get type hints for ESLint's new config file (eslint.config.js)?

Tags: eslint

In an `eslint.config.js` file, how can I get TypeScript type hints for the [new config](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new) object?

```js
/** @type {???} */
export default [
  {
    rules: {...}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You import declarations, including library types, to JSDoc using [import types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types). For your specific case the relevant type is [`FlatConfig`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/49953bca8a34847fba9ec46a2d573af229912949/types/eslint/index.d.ts#L846-L930), so:

```js
/** @type { import("eslint").Linter.FlatConfig[] } */
export default [
  // get hints here
];
```

Note you will need to install `@types/eslint` for `FlatConfig` to appear on `Linter`.

Comment: This should be included into eslint docs!
It should be here: https://eslint.org/docs/next/use/configure/configuration-files

Answer (score 0):

For typescript-eslint, here's what I am using:

```js
// @ts-check

/** @type {import("@typescript-eslint/utils/dist/ts-eslint/Linter").Linter.Config} c */
const config = {}

module.exports = config
```