# Is there a way to get an auto-complete for properties of .eslintrc.cjs file?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I started React/TypeScript project on vite.
I specified `"type": "module"` on `package.json` file because Vite's code splitting, faster hot module replacement etc. depend on ESM.
And I found that I must use `.eslintrc.cjs` file formats from [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats). But it seems `.eslintrc.cjs` file doesn't offer an "auto-complete" for properties of ESLint config.

```js
/* .eslintrc.cjs file */

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
    node: true,
  },
  ...
}
```

I've searched "JSDoc import type for eslint" to get auto-complete but couldn't reach the proper latest answer. Is there a way to get an auto-complete for the ESLint properties on `.cjs` file extension?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684118/how-do-i-get-type-hints-for-eslints-new-config-file-eslint-config-js (you want the older `Config`, rather than `FlatConfig`, but it's the same idea)?

Answer (score 0):

There currently does not appear to be an official eslint type declaration. But you can make your own. All rules provided by eslint can be found [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/main/packages/js/src/configs/eslint-all.js).

Like the following:

```js
// eslint.config.d.ts

type RulesKey = "accessor-pairs" |
    "array-callback-return" |
    "arrow-body-style" |
    "block-scoped-var"
    /* ... */
type RulesValue = 'error' | 'warn' | 'off'

interface EslintConfig {
    rules: {
        [key in RulesKey]?: RulesValue
    }
}
```

Then, You can use jsDoc in configuration files:

```js
// eslint.config.cjs

/** @type {Array<EslintConfig>} */
const eslint = [
    {
        rules: {
            "accessor-pairs": ''
        }
    }
]

module.exports = eslint
```

[picture1: Get key of rules tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EESmB.png)

[picture2: Get value of rules tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXSLU.png)

The above is just a simple example, and you can implement richer type declarations according to your needs.

I hope it was helpful for you :)